# Im not able to give a new corner radius to my view

Tags: swift

I'm creating some circles in a view, and I want to resize them to their previous position if they are somewhere near the next circle when I resize them with gestures on sender.state == .ended, they resize but it doesn't change the corner radius I want o give them on resize.

```
let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: a, height: a))

        circle.center = self.view.center
        circle.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(cornerRad)
        circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
        circle.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(b)
        circle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        circle.clipsToBounds = true

        let pinchCircle = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(changeSize))
        //let longPressCircle = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(erraseCircle))
        circle.addGestureRecognizer(pinchCircle)
        //circle.addGestureRecognizer(longPressCircle)

        self.view.addSubview(circle)
        arrayShapes.append(circle)
```

---

```
if let view = sender.view {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)

        let maxScale: CGFloat = 300 //Anything
        let minScale: CGFloat = 0.5 //Anything
        let scale = view.frame.size.width
        if scale > maxScale {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: maxScale / scale, y: maxScale / scale)
            arrFin[pos] = Double(view.frame.size.width)
        }
        else if scale < minScale {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: minScale / scale, y: minScale / scale)
            arrFin[pos] = Double(view.frame.size.width)
        } else {
            arrFin[pos] = Double(view.frame.size.width)
        }
        for (i, _) in arrayShapes.enumerated() {
            if arrayShapes[i].frame.width < view.frame.size.width{
                self.view.sendSubview(toBack: view)
            }
        }

        if sender.state == .ended {
            for (z, _) in arrFin.enumerated() where z != pos{
                let sum = arrFin[pos] - arrFin[z]
                let res = arrFin[z] - arrFin[pos]
                if arrFin[pos] == arrFin[z] || sum <= 20 || res >= 20{
                    arrFin[pos] = arrPos[pos]
                    sender.view?.layer.masksToBounds = true
                    sender.view?.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(arrPos[pos]) / 2
                    sender.view?.frame.size.width = CGFloat(arrPos[pos])
                    sender.view?.frame.size.height = CGFloat(arrPos[pos])
                    sender.view?.center = self.view.center
                    print(arrPos[pos])
                    break
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't understand your question. Could you explain more? Also, where does `arrPos` come from? It's never declared. Also don't calc `CGFloat(arrPos[pos]) / 2`, depending on what arrPos is, better use `CGFloat(arrPos[pos] / 2.0)`.

Comment: The problem is that when it goes back to the prev position, it changes the form of the circle to a diamond shape, even though im declaring that the shape should be with round edge in sender.view?.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(arrPos[pos]) / 2, and arrPos is just an array declared for the whole code to check previous positions. If you want me to i can give you a github with the proyect, as it is really hard to explain with just some lines of code.

Comment: Yes, please provide a project, so I can check it when I'm at home.

Comment: https://github.com/DiegoCach/orbits there you go, if you need any explanation of what i want to accomplish just tell me.

Comment: Don't worry i found a solution, the problem was the scaling changed all my values, i used CGAffineTransform.identity to resize and it worked, thanks anyways for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using `sender.view?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity` on the for loop instead of trying to force the size.
The problem was, that i was trying to resize to previous values but my scaling was messing those numbers up.